# Slow down a test with selenium on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium

I have a test for a drag & drop operation that passes fine when ran a tad slower but when running at normal (fast) speed, the drag&drop operation is ignored.

This seems related to the "onFinish" handler not finished when the second drag operation starts.

set_speed doesn't seem to work with selenium on rails. Any other idea ?

[edit]

Ok, I managed to make it work with:

```
command 'setSpeed', 500 # slow down the next operations
...
command 'setSpeed', 0   # get back to normal
```

Answer (score 0):

We have some similar tests in our application. we have created a custom web step

`"I wait (\d+) seconds"`

and after the dragging, we say

`"I wait 1 second"`

or in cases where it takes even longer

`"I wait 5 seconds"`

this way our other tests can run at faster speed.